What is the name of the movie of an aspiring painter whose dad robbed money to purchase his works?
Watched this when I was really young, so I only have a faint recollection of things.
The main character is an aspiring painter, but is struggling to make it big. Somehow he had a chance to display his works in a prestigious gallery. His dad (unsure if its foster, but definitely related) suddenly appears in his life again after being gone for years, and made him uneasy.
His works were later purchased under an anonymous name. He somehow got to know that his dad is in a dangerous situation and found him at a train station. His dad was chased by armed men, and was shot.
In the end, his dying dad revealed to him that he was the one who bought all of his works, as a kickstart to his career. The money was gotten through illegal means, and the armed men were after him and the money. He hugged his body while the train continues its run.

You're looking for  Great expectations

Modernization of Charles Dickens classic story finds the hapless Finn as a painter in New York pursuing his unrequited and haughty childhood love.





Yep, that's the one! Thank you very much!

No problem, glad I could help!
